# boost::asio how to read full buffer in right way?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I am learning the `boost::asio` and now confusing about the right way to read the full buffer. For example, when connection established I want to read `uint32_t` in next way:

```
std::uint32_t size;
size_t len = m_socket.read_some(buffer(&size, sizeof(std::uint32_t)));
```

As you see I set up the buffer size. In other case I received the `len` with length on `read_some` data.

So the main question: is the `boost::asio` guarantied that there are would be read all 4 bytes of `uint32_t` if I set up the needed buffer length when call `buffer`?

Or if it not guaranteed - how I can read full buffer? (all 4 bytes)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [`read_some`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/read_some/overload1.html) reference:

> This function is used to read data from the stream socket. The function call will block until **one or more** bytes of data has been read successfully, or until an error occurs.

With remarks:

> The read_some operation **may not read all** of the requested number of bytes. Consider using the `read` function if you need to ensure that the requested amount of data is read before the blocking operation completes.

So either you'll have to call `read_some` in a loop, or just call [`read`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/read/overload1.html), which will:

> block until one of the following conditions is true:
>
> - The supplied buffers are full. That is, the bytes transferred is equal to the sum of the buffer sizes.
> - An error occurred.
>
> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the stream's `read_some` function.

The usage of `read` in your case would be:

```
std::uint32_t size;
size_t len = read(m_socket, buffer(&size, sizeof(std::uint32_t)));
```